# Stretched alignment in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a *Panel*, in which I have a *TableLayoutPanel* object (having blue background in the picture). The *TableLayoutPanel's* *Dock* property is set to "*Top*".

My *TableLayoutPanel* has 1 row and 5 columns, each one having a fixed sized *Panel* in it (marked with red in the picture).

[image]

I would like to align these red panels horizontally (stretch in the remaining space but keep their size) in the following way in my *TableLayoutPanel* object: the remaining horizontal space in the right (which is not occupied by the red panels) to be divided in 6 and have this calculated space between each pair of panels.

Basically I would like to achieve the following design:
[image]

I believe there is a built in setting in the *TableLayoutPanel* for this (maybe in [TableLayoutPanel.ColumnsStyles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.columnstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) or [TableLayoutPanel.LayoutSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.layoutsettings(v=vs.110).aspx)), but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of your red panels, set the Anchor property to None.  This will cause the red panel to be centered within its cell.  As long as your columns are set to a width of 20% it should work the way you described.  I did it and got the results below.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Yes, this works fine. :-) It's a bit ugly that in case of having 5 red panels we have to set the width of columns to 20%. So when adding another column, we would have to set the width of all the columns to something 17% which makes this solution a bit un-robust. It would be nice a solution with only adding as many columns as we want and to have them arranged this way (without changing anything else). But at least this solves my current goal. Thanks for your time!